# Using Firebase foreach for querying and traversing

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have a Firebase query in Ionic 2 app. This is written in TypeScript. I am trying to retrieve all the users one by one based on a particular `familyId`.

Since I was not able to do a SQL-query-like for it. I am trying to retrieve one by one and compare it. Below is my code.

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('familyId');
    console.log("firebase executed");
    //var query = firebase.database().ref("users");
    let familyList: Array<string>;

    starCountRef.on("value",(snapshot) => {
        //console.log('users', snapshot.val());
         var users = snapshot.val();
        console.log("users", users);

        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
           var user = childSnapshot.val();
          // console.log("user", user);
          if(user.familyId == familyid){
                    console.log("entered", user);
                    //familyList.push(user.firstName);
                    this.userFamilyList.push(user);
            }
            return false; 
        });
    });
```

I am trying to use arrow functions because of my this references for the list which was failing before when using normal functions. But now `snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot))`, this returns a boolean according to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) to give a facility to stop emumeration.

So if I remove `return false` from my code, it gives me a compilation error:

```
[ts] Argument of type '(childSnapshot: DataSnapshot) => void' is not
assignable to parameter of type '(_0: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.  
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

How do I handle this condition? Is it only by adding `return false` or is there any other way to make the callback work without stopping enumerations? Thanks!

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/hiwubih/edit?js,console

Comment: But you can also just add the condition to the query: `firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('familyId').equalTo('familyidvaluethatyouwanttoload')`.

Comment: Returning `false` won't stop the enumeration; the enumeration is stopped if you return `true`. If you want to prevent the TypeScript error, returning `false` is probably the simplest option.